# Why isn't filesystem bigger than 4G bootable

Tags: iso, squashfs

I'm creating a custom ISO based on the official Ubuntu 16.04.

What I'm doing is simple:

1) mount the official Ubuntu iso to `/mnt`;
2) `cp /mnt/install/filesystem.squashfs /home`;
3) `cd /home && unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs`;
4) put my own files into `squashfs-root` and execute `mksquashfs squashfs-root filesystem.squashfs`;
5) `mkdir iso && cp -r /mnt/* iso/ && cp /home/filesystem.squashfs iso/install/`.

In a word, I put my things into `filesystem.squashfs` and rebuild an ISO file.

To build the ISO file, I execute `mkisofs -RJ -joliet-long -iso-level=4  -o test.iso iso/`.

At last, I get my ISO named `test.iso`.

However, this iso is not bootable because I put lots of files into it (the new `filesystem.squashfs` is 5.3G).

Google told me that it couldn't bigger than 4G.

So, is there a way to make a bootable ISO whose `filesystem.squashfs` is bigger than 4G?

Comment: The limit could be in that version of mkisofs, I suspect.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  Well, I can't even find the different versions of `mkisofs`.

Comment: AFAIK `mkisofs` has not been in development since around 2002.... There is an actively developed program called [xorriso](https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/web/wikis/Faq#xorriso_create_iso) ... Here is the [Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xorriso) If you install that program, you can get detailed information regarding your created iso image and the original image using: `xorriso -indev my_image.iso -report_system_area` ....